# Transition to CakePHP2

Tags: php, cakephp, documentation, cakephp-2.0

I am familar with CakePHP 1.3 and I would like to learn the novelties in CakePHP2.

I know there is the new [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/) and also the [migration guide](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/blob/master/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.rst). Still, I would like something broader than the migration guide without having to read all the cookbook again. I am thinking about something like a series of blog posts, in the spirit of the Django advent.

Is there anything like this around?

Comment: Uh?!? Why the close vote? I am just asking for documentation about the changes in a framework. Does this violate any policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At CakeFest this year Mark Story gave a presentation on the changes and they posted it as a [video of changes in 2.0](http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2011/10/06/ch-ch-anges_cakephp_2_0_-_by_mark_story). I found this to be a good high-level intro and might fit what you're looking for.

The other presentations from [CakeFest 2011](http://tv.cakephp.org/playlists/view/CakeFoundation/cakefest_2011_talks_-_uk) might be useful to you too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only things you need is [2.0 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html) and [New Features in CakePHP 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-0.html). Other thing is practice.

Comment: +1 Lottttttttttttttttttts of practice.

Comment: As long as you use the upgrade shell (use the latest version!) and follow the new naming conventions the only major things are depreciated methods (and a couple helpers!) that they removed and new (optional) features.